# Протоколы отсылки уведомления на приложение клиента

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, веб-служба, push-уведомления, webhook

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие протоколы существуют и чаще всего используются для отправки уведомления пользователю.

Допустим, есть настольное C# приложение. Я (разработчик) не знаю IP-адрес клиентского приложения. Но мне надо отправить ему уведомление / сообщение, чтобы программа выполнила какое-то действие.

2-й пример - любой мессенджер. Каким образом приложения понимают, что появилось новое сообщение и моментально его отображают в чате?

Comment: есть pull и push методы. Pull означает клиент периодически запрашивает сервер насчет новых сообщений, например тот же Long Pulling или обычный звпрос каждые X минут. Push означает, что сервер уведомляет клиента, в таких случаях используется двустороннее общение, например тот же SignalR.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо большое за ответ! На метаните глянул, что такое SignalR. Это как раз то, что мне нужно :)